# Getting debug error "; expected" after adding new ifclause to procedure

Tags: pascalscript, fastreport

After adding the `ifclause` for Art to a MasterReport to multiple the Netto total by `-1` for get a `-ve` result in the credit invoice, I am getting a `; expected` with the error indicator jumping to the procedure after it.

[Image of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjTgt.png)

It's likely a very stupid error but I can't wrap my head around the problem at the moment. Commenting the new ifclause out will resolve the issue so it's something with that.

```
procedure FooterSR1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
if ( <frxdsqryKopfdaten."MwStNichtAusweisbar"> = 0 ) then
   mmoBrutto.Memo.Text := FormatFloat('#,##0.00', EndBrutto ) + ' ' + <frxdsqryKopfdaten."CurrencyString">                                            
   else
   mmoBrutto.Memo.Text := FormatFloat('#,##0.00', EndNetto ) + ' ' + <frxdsqryKopfdaten."CurrencyString">;
end;  

procedure Hauptkopf1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  if (<frxdsqryArt."Art"> = 'Gutschrift') then
    begin                                    
      EndNetto := EndNetto * (-1)                                                                                                                                                                                        
    end else begin             
      EndNetto := EndNetto;
    end;
end;    
begin
  mmoNetto.Memo.Text := FormatFloat('#,##0.00', EndNetto ) + ' ' + frxdsqryKopfdaten."CurrencyString">
end;

procedure BandBankOnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
   if <frxdsqryFirma."Bank1"> <> '' then
           mmoBank.Visible := False           
   else
           mmoBank.Visible := FALSE;

   if <frxdsqryFirma."IBAN1"> <> '' then
   begin                     
           mmoIBAN.Visible := FALSE;  
           mmoBank.Visible := FALSE;  
           mmoBank.Height := 0                                                           
   end else begin                                                              
           mmoIBAN.Visible := FALSE;
           mmoBank.Visible := FALSE;                                                                         
   end;           
end;
```

Comment: I do not know Fast Report, but your code does not really look like a valid Pascal (Script) code. What's the point of the second `begin` ... `end` pair after `Hauptkopf1OnBeforePrint`? - You should really include a larger code snippet into the question, as your current snippet is most probably not enough to show the problem.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't too sure about how much to add code wise, I'll edit the post in that regard.

That said, the error doesn't occur when the iflcause from the Hauptkopf1OnBeforePrint is removed.

Comment: Note that you have 4 `begin`, but only 3 `end` in `Hauptkopf1OnBeforePrint`.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong (4× `begin`, but only 3× `end`):

```pascal
procedure Hauptkopf1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  if (<frxdsqryArt."Art"> = 'Gutschrift') then
    begin                                    
      EndNetto := EndNetto * (-1)                                                                                                                                                                                        
    end else begin             
      EndNetto := EndNetto;
    end;
end;    
begin
  mmoNetto.Memo.Text := FormatFloat('#,##0.00', EndNetto ) + ' ' + frxdsqryKopfdaten."CurrencyString">
end;
```

Your probably wanted this (but hard to say):

```pascal
procedure Hauptkopf1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  if (<frxdsqryArt."Art"> = 'Gutschrift') then
    begin                                    
      EndNetto := EndNetto * (-1)                                                                                                                                                                                        
    end else begin             
      EndNetto := EndNetto;
    end;
  end;    
  mmoNetto.Memo.Text := FormatFloat('#,##0.00', EndNetto ) + ' ' + frxdsqryKopfdaten."CurrencyString">
end;
```